# Closest match per group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that looks similar to this:

```
Motor MotorType CalibrationValueX CalibrationValueY
A     Car       1.2343            2.33343
B     Boat      1.2455            2.55434
B1    Boat      1.4554            2.11211
C     Car       1.4323            4.56555
D     Car       1.533             4.6666
..... 500 entries
```

In my SQL query, I am trying to find average of CalibrationValueY where CalibrationValueX is a certain value:

```
SELECT avg(CalibrationValueY), MotorType, Motor FROM MotorTable
WHERE CalibrationValueX = 1.23333
GROUP BY MotorType
```

This will not return anything, since there is not a CalibrationValueX value that equals exactly 1.23333.

I am able to find closest match separately for each MotorTable with:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CalibrationValueY, FileSize, MotorType, Motor FROM MotorTable
where FileType = 'text' order by abs(FileSize - 1.23333)
```

however, I can't get it to work with a group by statement.
How can I do it so that if I am grouping by MotorType and I am searching CalibrationValueX = 1.23333, I would get this:

```
A     Car       1.2343            2.33343
B     Boat      1.2455            2.55434
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` You combinate `TOP 1` for each group

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47096/2)**

```
with cte as (
    SELECT MotorType, CalibrationValueX, CalibrationValueY,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by MotorType order by abs(CalibrationValueX - 1.23333)) rn
    from historyCR
)
SELECT *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

### OUTPUT

```
| MotorType | CalibrationValueX | CalibrationValueY | rn |
|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|----|
|      Boat |            1.2455 |           2.55434 |  1 |
|       Car |            1.2343 |           2.33343 |  1 |
```

Comment: I had basically the exact same solution :)

Comment: @mellamokb Was easy, took me longer writting the sqlfiddle